# Преобразовать строковую переменную с кодом символа типа "#1060" в символ

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Собственно есть строка строка с кодами символов - "#1060#1072#1085" из нее копируется в переменную код символа "#1060". теперь его нужно преобразовать в символ.

код

```
ach: PWideChar;
t: string;
ach := WideChar(#1060);
WideCharToStrVar(ach, t);
```

прекрасно возвращает символ Ф.
при попытке

```
ach: PWideChar;
t, t1: string;
t1 := '#1060';
ach := WideChar(t1);
WideCharToStrVar(ach, t);
```

выдает ошибку. Явно упускаю что-то промежуточное - но не могу понять что... С Юникодом работал мало. ANSI хватало с головой.

Comment: Я как-то устал тоже во всяких конвертациях, нашел в википедии стандарты KOI8R, WIN1251, UTF8, ASCII и написал свою процедуру перевода из одного в другое. По стандарту можно по некоторым признакам узнать кодировку, но никто эти стандарты не поддерживает! Особенно у нас. И процедура автоматического определения кодировки, потерпела фиаско :)
Но если посмотреть на коды символов в разных кодировках, можно найти то отличие, по которому можно определить автоматически кодировку.
В консольных приложениях всегда 866 кодировка и в редакторе меняя её на 866, сразу пишешь на русском, понятному консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часть строки нужно преобразовать в число.

```
var
   ch: WideChar;
   t1: string;
begin
  t1 := '#1060';
  ch := WideChar(Copy(t1, 2, length(t1)).ToInteger);
  Caption := ch;
```

Если выделять из исходной строки без `#`, то и `Copy` не понадобится

```
t1 := '1060';
ch := WideChar(t1.ToInteger);
```

Comment: Мдя а слоника то я и не заметил. Все заработало. наглядный пример "туннельного восприятия". Спасибо.

Comment: Там я помню TEncode класс с конвертацией работает в современных Delphi 10+. Почитайте дополнительно про него. Там даже при загрузки файла есть перегружаемый метод с параметром Encode, который автоматом в UTF8, ANSI,ASCII ... (нет WIN1251) конвертирует.
А так вы по 1 символу собираетесь конвертить?

Comment: другого варианта не вижу. собственно формат строки - " &#1060;&#1072;&#1085;&#1090;&#1072;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080;&#1082;&#1072; / &#1092;&#1101;&#1085;&#1090;&#1077;&#1079;&#1080; - News  "  русские буквочки кодом. остальные - символами. плюс еще фигня с BBcode

Comment: Добавлю от себя. Команда k=k+WideChar(t1.ToInteger) по скорости не очень эффективна. Тут лучше k сразу сделать длинной строкой (к примеру 1000 символов с запасом), потом  k[i]=WideChar(t1.ToInteger) и в самом конце через SetLength обрезать под нужный размер. Так было раньше.

Comment: смысл? проще ansipos('&#'). copy, widechar, и replese('&#1060;', ch)